# Hostgator remotely access database in local php file

Tags: php, mysql, database, remote-access

I am currently using HostGator but my problem is I cannot connect to my online database (which is the HostGator) using my `localhost` PHP file. I want that if I have internet connection I will connect to my online database but if none I will connect to my offline `localhost` database. Here's my code:

```
$checknet = @fsockopen("www.mysite.com", 80);

if(isset($checknet)) {
    mysql_connect('mysite.com OR ip of mysite','username','password');
    mysql_select_db('db');
} else {
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('db');
}
```

Also, I already added my IP address to the access whitelist of the database. But, accessing the database from a remote system still doesn't work.

Comment: Does PHP return some sort of error? That usually explains what is going on if there's a problem with your code. Also, are you sure your database is called `db`, and not something like `username_db`?

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\cose\db.php on line 5

this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to whitelist your public IP address.

> a) Google "what is my ip"
>
> b) Follow the tutorial on [this link](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-whitelist-your-ip-in-cpanel-for-remote-mysql-access/).

Comment: I already try this one but still not luck. Is there any possible way to grant access using php code?